# Cant execute ansible playbook (libselinux python arent installed)

Tags: python, linux, ansible

Originally when executing ansible playbook to run on a server I was getting the following error

```
/usr/bin/python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
<171.16.3.112> (1, '', 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "<stdin>", line 133, in ?\n  File "<stdin>", line 38, in invoke_module\n  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 1050, in communicate\n    stdout, stderr = self._communicate_with_poll(input)\n  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 1113, in _communicate_with_poll\n    input_offset += os.write(fd, chunk)\nOSError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe\n')
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 133, in ?
  File "<stdin>", line 38, in invoke_module
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 1050, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate_with_poll(input)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 1113, in _communicate_with_poll
    input_offset += os.write(fd, chunk)
OSError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

fatal: [171.16.3.112]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"<stdin>\", line 133, in ?\n  File \"<stdin>\", line 38, in invoke_module\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py\", line 1050, in communicate\n    stdout, stderr = self._communicate_with_poll(input)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py\", line 1113, in _communicate_with_poll\n    input_offset += os.write(fd, chunk)\nOSError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
    "rc": 1
}
        to retry, use: --limit @/root/ansible-setup/users.retry

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
171.16.3.112               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

So I thought I would fix this issue by upgrading the Python version on the 171.16.3.112 server from 2.4.3 to 2.7.5

I followed: https://techglimpse.com/linux-how-to-upgrade-python-2-4-to-2-7-or-higher-manually/

Once the upgrade was completed now when I execute ansible I am getting this error:

```
            "insertbefore": null,
            "line": "%users    ALL=(isas1)   NOPASSWD: ALL",
            "mode": null,
            "owner": null,
            "path": "/etc/sudoers",
            "regexp": "^%users",
            "remote_src": null,
            "selevel": null,
            "serole": null,
            "setype": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "src": null,
            "state": "present",
            "unsafe_writes": null,
            "validate": null
        }
    },
    "msg": "Aborting, target uses selinux but python bindings (libselinux-python) aren't installed!"
}
        to retry, use: --limit @/root/ansible-setup/users.retry

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
171.16.3.112                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I tried yum install libselinux-python but that did not work.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: that is the requirement, the library is needed on the target server so Ansible can correctly handle the selinux contexts. Please refer the below link. https://dmsimard.com/2016/01/08/selinux-python-virtualenv-chroot-and-ansible-dont-play-nice/

Comment: "I tried yum install libselinux-python but that did not work". In what way didn't it work? Same error? Different error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aborting, target uses selinux but Python bindings (libselinux-Python) aren't installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63173955/aborting-target-uses-selinux-but-python-bindings-libselinux-python-arent-ins)