# Aborting, target uses selinux but Python bindings (libselinux-Python) aren't installed

Tags: python, ansible

I am trying to run Ansible playbook command and getting an error as below.

> ```
> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Aborting, target
> uses selinux but python bindings (libselinux-python) aren't installed!"}
> ```

When I checked for libselinux-python, it showsit is already available.

```
[root@host all]# sudo yum list installed |grep libselinux-python
libselinux-python3.x86_64            2.5-15.el7              @rhel-7-server-rpms
```

Please provide your input if anyone has faced and resolved this.

Below are my Python and Ansible versions installed on server.

```
[root@ xxx bin]# python --version
Python 3.6.5

[root@xxx bin]# which python
/root/.pyenv/shims/python

[root@xxx bin]# ansible --version
ansible 2.9.9
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.5 (default, Jun 18 2020, 17:32:20) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]

[root@ xxx bin]#
```

Answer (score 45):

I've just lost a whole day to this and I managed to solve it running `sudo yum install libselinux-python3`

Comment: `No package libselinux-python3 available.`. What OS are you on? (I'm on Amazon Linux 2)

Comment: ansible complained on libselinux-python but it is libselinux-python3 that is missing. This happened on CentOS.

Answer (score 16):

Or alternatively one can install selinux in your current Python venv: `pip install selinux`.

Comment: This is the correct answer for venvs, see the description of this package at https://pypi.org/project/selinux/ (TLDR: a shim for exactly this situation). Note you still need `sudo yum install libselinux-python3` or equivalent.

Comment: This was the solution for me in combination with setting ansible_python_interpreter to my venv. I did installed also libselinux-python3 and libselinux-python. Only the installation did not help, only the pip install neither. Only when i did tied up everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 6):

Below is what I've done to get around this problem.

For Python3 on RHEL, you can install SE Linux with

```
sudo yum install -y libselinux-python3
```

Then create a virtual environment to isolate your dependencies and give it access to the system site-packages directory:

```
python3 -m venv .venv --system-site-packages
```

If you don't use `--system-site-packages`, your virtual environment won't be able to access selinux since its placed in `/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages`.

Then activate this virtual environment and run your ansible playbook commands:

```
source .venv/bin/activate
ansible-playbook -i my_inventory my_playbook.yml -vvv
deactivate
```

Its usually bad practice to modify `PYTHONPATH` as shown in one of the below answers, even though it works.

Answer (score 6):

These answers may be a little old now, so I'll say that while using Rocky Linux 8.4 (RHEL clone) the package names in `dnf` have changed from the Ansible docs. Ansible says it should be `policycoreutils-python` but it's actually `python3-policycoreutils` and `python3-libselinux`.

So you can install it with:

```
dnf install python3-policycoreutils python3-libselinux
```

Answer (score 2):

Leaving this answer here as it may help someone.

In my case I was receiving the dreaded `"Aborting, target uses selinux but python bindings (libselinux-python) aren't installed!"` while running my Ansible playbook even though I had `libselinux-python` package installed on my target host. Even though the ansible python interpreter was using `python2.7` on the target, I decided to install `libselinux-python3` as well, to no avail.

After hours of debugging, it turns out the issue stemmed from the shell environment of the user on the target host under which the ansible tasks were running.

What was happening is that this playbook created a user on the target host, created a python virtual environment for this user and set the `PYTHON_PATH` of  this user to his python virtual environment. And since the ansible `interpreter_python` was set to `python`, when the `template` tasks were running as this user it used his custom python environment which of course does not inherit the `libselinux-python` from the OS and the error message was generated.

I removed the custom `PYTHON_PATH=/path/to/env/python` from this user's `~/.bash_profile` and lo and behold the playbook works!

**TL;DR**: Check that the user under which the ansible tasks that fails runs on the target host does not have a custom python environment set in his environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this for awhile, even after reading the answers here.  My confusion was that while I did need to install libselinux-python3 I needed it on the *host* machines.  I kept installing it on the ansible server and not understanding why that didn't work, because I'm an idiot ;).

To ensure that the library was installed on every host I added an extra line to install libselinux-python3 before I run any of the modules dependent on it.

```
- name: install python selinux library required by future ansible modules
  become: true
  yum:
    name: libselinux-python3
    state: present
    update_cache: true
```

this fixed my later commands that were previously failing.

Comment: Except for RHEL 7.9, the name of the package is `python3-libselinux` I believe. On RHEL 7.9, it is called `libselinux-python`.

Answer (score 1):

selinux package installed under /usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages was not accessible by python ansible. After configuring PYTHONPATH in .bash_profile. issue got resolved.

export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages

Answer (score 1):

Modify as you wish but this is what worked for me:

```
- name: Install pip
  vars:
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python
  yum:
    name: python-pip
    update_cache: yes
    state: present

- name: Install python modules
  pip:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: present
  environment:
    HTTP_PROXY: 'http://your-proxy.com:80'
    HTTPS_PROXY: 'http://your-proxy.com:80'
  with_items:
  - { name: selinux }
```

Comment: I wish I had looked at this post more closely.   We are using python3 on amazonlinux2 so ansible runs under python 2.7 but the playbooks are mostly written for python 3.

adding vars: ansible_python_interpreter: (just blank) fixed the issue for us.

Answer (score 1):

For me this issue happened after I migrated a RHEL7 to RHEL8 and changed python3 alternative package to Python3.11:

```
alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.11
alternatives --set python3 /usr/bin/python3.11
```

and then it was fixed when I changed it to:

```
alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3
alternatives --set python3 /usr/bin/python3.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing libselinux-python3 on both node and host didn't work for me until I install pip install selinux on the host(the one which has ansible on it) did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

We recently added some RHEL 8 hosts to our environment and I got a similar error message the first time I tried to run a playbook on one. I verified that python3-libselinux was installed on the target host. I finally tracked my issue down to the default transport method in our ansible.cfg file - someone had changed it to "paramiko". I set it back to "smart" and was able to run the play without any further errors.

Answer (score 0):

**selinux & hosts: localhost**

A can see "[localhost]" in your error log, so for me you are in the same condition as me, it means in your playbook you have `hosts: localhost` to execute the task on your Ansible control node.

`localhost` is defined with specific connection variables equivalent to this in an inventory:

```
localhost:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: local
    ansible_python_interpreter: "{{ ansible_playbook_python }}"
```

which is equivalent to `ansible_playbook_python: venv/bin/python3`

So, you have to check if `libselinux-python3` is installed on the control node and you configure your virtualenv with the parameter `--system-site-packages`.

I don't know if it's mandatory but sometimes we had to install python bindings with a requirements file:

```
selinux==<VERSION_COMPATIBLE_WITH_YOUR_PYTHON>
```

(I have to dig this part)

**selinux & delegate_to: localhost**

In you contexte, it's [localhost] is not [test_host => localhost] so it's not a `delegate_to: localhost` but the same problem may occur.
You execute it on the Ansible control node with a venv (python version 3.8) but locahost get all the host_vars from the `test_host`, and maybe there is only python 2.7 for exemple. So it doesn't use libselinux-python3 installed on the control node and don't find the libselinux-python for python 2.7.

So, setting:

```
vars:
  ansible_python_interpreter: "/usr/bin/python3"
```

for the tasks executed with `delegate_to: localhost` will correct that.

Answer (score 0):

Our team uses pre-baked and pre-hardened Amazon Linux 2 AMI images. Someone hardened newer image updates from `SELINUX=disabled` to `SELINUX=permissive`, but didn't document the change.

When we began to test the new images, Ansible broke with the same error because we didn't usually install `libselinux-python` until *after* we tried writing a template to disk.

We'll need to change our order of operations now to install the package before Ansible runs to make sure it's able to write to disk.

For a quick fix, `SELINUX=disabled` could be a (very temporary) workaround but is definitely not the correct permanent solution like @Kevin C above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you are use Redhat8.8, make sure you python link to  /usr/libexec/platform-python or /usr/libexec/platform-python3.6 at last.Then it should works!

```
# rpm -qa | grep libselinux
libselinux-2.9-8.el8.i686
python3-libselinux-2.9-8.el8.x86_64
libselinux-2.9-8.el8.x86_64
libselinux-utils-2.9-8.el8.x86_64

# ll /usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/se
selinux/                      selinux-2.9-py3.6.egg-info    semanage.py                   setools/                      setools-4.3.0-py3.6.egg-info/
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was I was running `pip3 install --user selinux` which was installing the package in `~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`.

While importing it was searching in

```
[/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages, /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages, /usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages, /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages]
```

and hence wasn't able to find.
To fix I ran the installation with root permissions

```
sudo pip3 install selinux
```

This put the package in the `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`

Answer (score 0):

Many of the answers above already mention it, just to reiterate.

Using Ansible on a system with multiple versions of python, for instance following these steps on Rocky 9.3:

```
python3.11 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -U pip
pip install ansible
pip install selinux
```

And following that with `yum install libselinux-python3` makes a skew in the libraries.

The error pops up because 'selinux' (using python3.11) cant find 'libselinux' which is installed on a system using python3.9 .

So far the path of least resistance would be to reinstall ansible with the system level python3.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had to just set `SELINUX=disabled` in `/etc/selinux/config` file.

Comment: That's not solving the problem, but circumventing it